# How do I parse an value that can be an object or a string - Java - Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I am using `Jackson` to deserialize some `xml`.  My `xml` has a value that can be an object or a string.  Here is my `xml`

```
<FormFieldHidden name="RequestTime">
  <DefaultValue>
    <DataSourceName>DataSourceCurrentTime</DataSourceName>
  </DefaultValue>
</FormFieldHidden>
<FormFieldHidden name="TradPtnrID">
  <DefaultValue>043355932</DefaultValue>
</FormFieldHidden>
```

Here is my java:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Forms {

    public Form form;

    public Forms() {
      form = new Form();
    }

    public static class Form extends Asset {
      public String version;
      public String description;

    public List<Section> sections;

    }

    public static class Section {
      public String label;
      public int totalColumns;
    public List<FormFieldHidden> formFields;
    }

    public static class FormFieldHidden {
      public String defaultValue;
    }
}
```

How can I pull out the `defaultValue` whether it is an object or string?

Comment: What kind of object? and what fields are in it? I have done some JSON parsing with Jackson. Looks like you need to create your own `deserializer` class to that `defaultValue` field and maybe it should be `public Object defaultValue` then.

Answer (score 0):

I havent work with Jackson but maybe `instanceof` will help,
in pseudocode

```
if (value instanceof Class){Class c=value;}
else{String s=value;}
```